Sizing a crush washer
This is a general question. Repair manuals often don't state the dimensions or materials of crush washers. If you Google it, crush washer dimensions are only reported in terms of the OD (outer diameter) rather than the (ID) inner diameter and they don't say copper vs aluminum. It isn't practical to find out in the middle of a job, especially if it's your only car and the store is out of stock!
So what's the deal? Can you nip up a calipers on the washer, find the OD, and then Bob's Your Uncle - the ID is standard and it doesn't matter if you use copper vs aluminum?

What exactly is the crush washer for? I mean, if you're putting a crush washer on a banjo bolt for a brake caliper, it should be copper and is usually a common size. I'm thinking there should actually be three dimensions you'd be worried about: Inner; outer; thickness.

Not answering your question, so just a comment. If you're ever stuck without a required copper crush washer and it's a choice between getting back on the road or calling an Uber, you can re-use the old crush washer one time by annealing it. Heat it to cherry red in a propane torch for a moment, then let it cool naturally. Clean up any ridges with a fine flat file. It will crush just like new, but a little thinner.

@Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2 in this case, I am considering crush washers for transmissions. Wife's car (2010 Mazda 3) has a dipstick and drains from a drainplug/weldnut in the transmission pan. Family van (2018 Odyssey EXL) has a 3 plugs (drain/fill/level) and I see from videos the OEM washer is rubber.
